# What is the solution of this Ordinary Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

How can I find $y(x)$ that solve this:
$$ x(y^2 - 6) - (x^2 - 8)yy' = 0$$
$$ y(\sqrt{8}) = -\sqrt{6} $$

Comment: **Hint:** It is a Separable ODE, so separate, integrate, use the IC and simplify.

Comment: @Moo But $y'$ is not converges at $D \subseteq R^2$ while $( \sqrt{8} , -\sqrt{6}) \in D$

Comment: No, that point does not belong to $D$, if $D$ is to be the domain of the ODE encoded by this equation. At the given point there is no unique, not even locally unique, value for $y'$.

Comment: @Moo Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

We separate the variables, in  $$x(y^2 - 6) - (x^2 - 8)yy' = 0$$

to get $$ \frac {ydy}{y^2-6} = \frac {xdx}{x^2-8}$$

Upon integration and solving for $y$ we get  $$ y=-\sqrt {6+c(x^2-8)}$$

Where c is an arbitrary constant as long as the radicand stays non-negative.

Comment: But how can you separate the variables ? It's not defined at $(\sqrt{8}, -\sqrt{6})$..

Comment: That is OK, at this point we do not have a specific initial condition in mind. As you notice, there are solutions which satisfy the initial condition. The solution is not unique which is an interesting point to notice.

Answer (score 0):

$$x(y^2 - 6) - (x^2 - 8)yy' = 0$$
$$x(y^2 - 6) - (\frac 12 x^2 - 4)2yy' = 0$$
$$x(y^2 - 6) - (\frac 12 x^2 - 4)(y^2)' = 0$$

you have the form $f'g-fg'$ Divide by $g^2$ and get the form $(\frac f g)'=0$

for $x \pm \ne \sqrt 8$ 
$$\left (\frac {y^2-6}{\frac 12 x^2-4} \right)'= 0$$

Integrate ...

Answer (score 0):

From the initial equation we draw

$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt6\iff x=\sqrt8\lor y'(x)=0.$$

Hence,

$$y(x)=-\sqrt6$$ fulfills the conditions.

We also draw

$$x=0\iff y(x)=0\lor y'(x)=0$$

and

$$x=\pm\sqrt8\iff y(x)=\pm\sqrt 6.$$

Now, assuming that $x^2\ne8\land y^2(x)\ne 6$, the integration of the separable equation yields

$$y^2(x)-6=C(x^2-8).$$

Finally we have the solutions

- $y(x)=-\sqrt6$,
- $y(x)=\begin{cases}x=\sqrt8\to -\sqrt6,\\x\ne\sqrt8\to \pm\sqrt{6+C(x^2-8)}\end{cases}$, where the positive sign must be rejected to ensure differentiability.

This is summarized by

$$y(x)=-\sqrt{6+C(x^2-8)},$$ a family of half-hyperbolas and -ellipses with the special cases

$$y(x)=-\sqrt6,
\\y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt3}2|x|.$$